# Ruby on Rails - List Cities with most recent updated timestamp for Place

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model `Place`, that has a `city`, `state`, timestamps, etc.  Obviously, I can have multiple `Place` records in a given `city`.

What I need (for my sitemap) list of `Place` records, distinct by `city` and returning the `updated_at` for the most recently changed `Place` for that `city`.

Note: I have an `in_state` scope, which adds `where(Place.arel_table[:state_abbr].matches(state_abbr)`

Here's where I'm at:

```
Place.select(:city, :updated_at).in_state("IL").group(:city, :updated_at).order(:city).distinct
```

This is returning records with duplicate cities, etc. I've tried all different combinations and my brain is pretty burned out. I know this is trivial, but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
Place.select(:city, max(:updated_at)).in_state("IL").group(:city).order(:city)
```

Comment: `Place.select(:city, maximum(:updated_at)).in_state(state_abbr.downcase).group(:city).order(:city)`  => `NoMethodError: undefined method \`maximum' for main:Object`

Comment: `NoMethodError: undefined method \`max' for main:Object`

Comment: Here we go: `Place.select("places.city, max(places.updated_at)").in_state(state_abbr.downcase).approved.group(:city).order(:city)` ... Can that be made more Rails-y?